# Set a computed field to use a bitmap's original size when using bitmap()

Tags: bitmap, powerbuilder, autosize

I have a computed field that displays a bitmap via the compute expression on a datawindow.

```
bitmap(logo_file_path)
```

It displays the logo but it scales the image to the width and height determined via the computed field's property. Instead I want it to use the original size of the image.

I've tried setting the width to 0 and height to 0 but that doesn't work. I've also tried setting autosize height but it does not do what I'm expecting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

First you should get the dimensions of the image and then resize computed field with new width and height.

It's easy. Get image binary and store it in a `Blob` variable (in examples, *lblb_image*)

### For BMP file

```
ll_width  = Long(Integer(BlobMid(lblb_image, 19, 2)), Integer(BlobMid(lblb_image, 21, 2)))
ll_height = Long(Integer(BlobMid(lblb_image, 23, 2)), Integer(BlobMid(lblb_image, 25, 2)))
```

### For GIF file

```
ll_width  = asc(string(blobMid(lblb_image, 7, 2)))
ll_height = asc(string(blobMid(lblb_image, 9, 2)))
```

### For JPG file

```
Byte lby_jpegMark1[5] = {255, 192, 0, 17, 8}    // 0xFF 0xC0 0x00 0x11 0x08
Byte lby_jpegMark2[5] = {255, 192, 0, 17, 12}   // 0xFF 0xC0 0x00 0x11 0x0C

LONG    ll_pos

Byte    lby_byte
Byte    lby_highByte
Byte    lby_lowByte

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// JPG file?
if ( GetByte(lblb_image, 1) = 255 And GetByteGetByte(lblb_image, 2) = 216 ) then
else
    return
end if

ll_pos = 3

// Dimension block is after 0xFF 0xC0 0x00 0x11 0x08 or 0xFF 0xC0 0x00 0x11 0x0C
do while (ll_pos <= Len(lblb_image) )
    lby_byte = GetByte(lblb_image, ll_pos)
    // Start of a marker (JPEG markers begin with 0xFF)
    if ( lby_byte = 255 ) then
        // Next byte tell us block type
        choose case ( GetByte(lblb_image, ll_pos + 1) )
            case 224 to 239         // 0xE1 a 0xEF
                // Application data. Ignore
                // Next 2 bytes are block size
                lby_highByte = GetByte(lblb_image, ll_pos + 2)
                lby_lowByte  = GetByte(lblb_image, ll_pos + 3)
                ll_pos += GetByte(lby_lowByte, lby_highByte) 
                continue

            case lby_jpegMark1[2]   // 0xC0
                // Info block. This is it
                if ( GetByte(lblb_image, ll_pos + 2) = lby_jpegMark1[3] and &
                     GetByte(lblb_image, ll_pos + 3) = lby_jpegMark1[4] and &
                    (GetByte(lblb_image, ll_pos + 4) = lby_jpegMark1[5] or GetByte(lblb_image, ll_pos + 4) = lby_jpegMark2[5]) ) then
                    // Block found
                    ll_pos += 5
                    exit
                else
                    ll_pos += 5
                    continue
                end if
        end choose
    end if

    ll_pos++
loop

if ( ll_pos > Len(lblb_image) ) then return

// Height calculation (2 bytes and combine into a 16-bit integer value)
lby_highByte = GetByte(lblb_image, ll_pos)
lby_lowByte  = GetByte(lblb_image, ll_pos + 1)
ii_height    = lby_lowByte + (lby_highByte * 256) 

ll_pos += 2

// Width calculation (2 bytes and combine into a 16-bit integer value)
lby_highByte = GetByte(lblb_image, ll_pos)
lby_lowByte  = GetByte(lblb_image, ll_pos + 1)
ii_width     = lby_lowByte + (lby_highByte * 256)
```

For other formats, Google. ;-)